# Ubuntu change default file/folder permission of specific user

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-12.04, user-permissions

How can i make any folders or files created by a certain user always be public(775) in Ubuntu.

Comment: You should ask this on http://askubuntu.com instead. (You have to set umask in user's profile - Sorry, I don't have access to my ubuntu box now, so I cannot try out and give more specific advice.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this from AskUbuntu. Hope it helps anyone.

> You edit the user file-creation mode mask (umask) of that user. There
>   are several ways to do this, one way would be to add umask xxx (xxx is
>   your desired umask) to your ~/.profile and relog. This won't affect
>   already existing files though.
>
> See Wikipedia umask for information about umask and how to calculate
>   one.